# Cache images fetched via background-url CSS property

Tags: html, browser-cache

How can I have images fetched via the `background-url` CSS attribute cached in the browser?

The browser will automatically cache images (and other resources) fetched, assuming there are appropriate headers and the URL for the request is the same.

When using the `background-url` property, I see that the headers `cache-control: no-cache` and `pragma: no-cache` are added automatically.

This prevents browser caching.

I was surprised by this behavior, you can reproduce it with this simple [codepen](https://codepen.io/donpinkus/pen/zYWxJPQ) and filtering your network tab to images.

Comment: If an image was already cached and it is loading in a quicker manner as an `img` tag, then is the cache being used when it is being loaded into CSS as a background-image? If so, then I have an idea for a solution.

Comment: Are you using SASS or LESS in your code ?

Comment: The remote server sets headers and cache behavior, right? So your question is (I think): how is it possible to influence the remote server to set different cache headers (or skip them altogether)? [Your example](https://cdn.jdpower.com/dimensions%20of%20a%20firetruck.jpg) responds fine when curl'ing directly: `content-type: image/jpeg` and `content-length: 305999` so the data looks good, but also `cf-cache-status: HIT` (cache hit in Cloudflare's CDN) and `max-age=604800` (one week).

Comment: Following your [codepen](https://codepen.io/donpinkus/pen/zYWxJPQ) example, the outbound request shows: 
`cache-control: no-cache` and `pragma: no-cache`.
But after the initial request, I see subsequent requests are cached by Cloudflare (various `cf-` things in response headers, including `cf-cache-status: HIT`). What is it you're seeing specifically that shows you it _isn't_ being cached?

Comment: Can't repro. Subsequent fetches come from memory cache for me, on both Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that the caching is just disabled by the browser's developer tools.
E.g. "Disable cache" checkbox in Google Chrome's Network panel.

I've tested it with your codepen and confirm:

- with "Disable cache" checked Chrome adds the request headers cache-control: no-cache and pragma: no-cache
- with the checkbox unchecked these headers are not added and the caching works as expected

So I think it's a non-issue?

Comment: This can be tested further by requesting other resources in the codepen with the "Disable cache" button checked and see if they are being sent with "cache-control: no-cache" and "pragma: no-cache".

Answer (score 0):

You're request headers aren't set to tell the browser to cache the image (also found in that same "Headers" tab that you would have seen that Status Code if the browser actually went to the server for the image). You'll want to set cache-control and expires to something that makes sense for you. Cache headers can get a bit complicated you may want to browse.

For SSL not all browsers cache this but most modern browsers do. Set cache-control: public on these images (and also expires).

[Caching for web](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/)